# How to send Mail through data base Using sql server 2005?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i want to develop an application where need to set reminder and send mail through database on particular time duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please goto the following links for sending Email using SqlServer 2005

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/02/how-to-send-email-using-sql-server-2005.html

Comment: You Have Asked A Very Nice Question

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Database Mail.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(SQL.90).aspx

You can then create the process logic that calls the stored procedure [sp_send_dbmail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) in order to send mail.

You can then schedule your process/stored procedure using a SQL Server Agent job.

Answer (score 0):

These examples are [from here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx):

> **Sending an e-mail message**
>
> This example sends an e-mail message
>   to Dan Wilson using the e-mail address
>   danw@Adventure-Works.com. The message
>   has the subject Automated Success
>   Message. The body of the message
>   contains the sentence 'The stored
>   procedure finished successfully'.
>
> ```
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
> @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks Administrator',
> @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
> @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
> @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
> ```
>
> **Sending an e-mail message with the results of a query**
>
> This example sends an e-mail message
>   to Dan Wilson using the e-mail address
>   danw@Adventure-Works.com. The message
>   has the subject Work Order Count, and
>   executes a query that shows the number
>   of work orders with a DueDate less
>   than two days after April 30, 2004.
>   Database Mail attaches the result as a
>   text file.
>
> ```
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
> @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks Administrator',
> @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
> @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder
>               WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''
>               AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
> @subject = 'Work Order Count',
> @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
> ```